# Atomic Gem on Centos 6.5?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, atomic, centos6

I had a problem a couple of months ago and somehow fixed it. Since then, a certain webhosting company did a forced upgrade on my server that pretty-much broke everything. This is the last piece that needs to be corrected and I cannot figure this out on my own.

I have a Rails 4 project that has a dependency on the Atomic gem, version 1.1.14. This works fine locally on OSX Mavericks, and on a staging server (Centos 5.6 I believe) but will not work on the production server.

- Centos 6.5
- 64bit
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rubygems 2.2.2
- gcc 4.8.2

I installed the newest gcc because I found a forum post saying it should work with that, but no dice.

On the server, running `gem install atomic -v 1.1.14` supposedly works but then deploying via Capistrano, running `bundle install` fails giving the following error:

```
* 2014-02-11 09:51:08 executing `bundle:install'
* executing "cd /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/subdomain/releases/20140211145013 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/subdomain/releases/20140211145013/Gemfile --path /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/subdomain/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
servers: ["subdomain.example.com"]
[subdomain.example.com] executing command
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Your Gemfile lists the gem database_cleaner (>= 0) more than once.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] You should probably keep only one of them.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] 
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-cflags=-march=i686
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] *** extconf.rb failed ***
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] details.  You may need configuration options.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] 
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Provided configuration options:
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-opt-dir
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-opt-dir
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-opt-include
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-opt-lib
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-make-prog
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-make-prog
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --srcdir=.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --curdir
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-atomic_reference-dir
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-atomic_reference-dir
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-atomic_reference-include
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --with-atomic_reference-lib
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/lib
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] You have to install development tools first.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:712:in `try_run'
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] 
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] extconf failed, exit code 1
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] 
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/subdomain/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Results logged to /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/subdomain/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1-static/atomic-1.1.14/gem_make.out
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
** [out :: subdomain.example.com] Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
command finished in 6952ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

The part that really confuses me is that it's using this flag, if I understand it correctly `--with-cflags=-march=i686` which is a 32bit thing, is it not?

If anyone knows a fix for this or could give me a little bit of direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? You have several messages that suggest you are missing the headers and development tools necessary. I've seen similar problems when installing Ruby via a repo, instead of from source.

Comment: It was an RPM. Is there a way around it or are we talking about uninstalling ruby and installing from the source?